# Android Mobile : Links not working on Tap with JqTouch

Tags: android, mobile, hyperlink, jqtouch

I'm developing a mobile version with JqTouch.

I have some troubles with simple buttons (`<a href=""></a>` links) not reacting on Tap with Android Phones. Nothing happens and there even no orange outline around the link when I touch it. Everything works fine on iPhone mobiles.

I tried to disable my CSS sheet, but same result. What am I doing wrong? Is this a common issue with Android browsers?

Here is my code

```
    <div id="homeLang" class="current">
        <div class="scroll">

            <div id="lang">
                <a id="frBtn" class="btn" href="#fr">FR</a>
                <a id="nlBtn" class="btn" href="#nl">NL</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a common issue on Android. Have you tried to run some of the demos that comes with jqtouch on Android, do you get the same issue there?

I just tried the following and it works on both iPhone and Android devices.

```
<div id="test">
   <ul class="rounded">
      <li><a href="#page2">Go to page 2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div id="page2">
   <a href="#" class="whiteButton goback">Go back to page 1</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem.  Internal links in jQtouch don't work with Android, but work on iPhone.  Switch from using jQuery to Zepto.  That will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but for future users looking for this answer, I believe you'll get it working by doing the following when instantiating your jQT object:

```
var jQT = new $.jQTouch({
  useFastTouch: false
});
```